# How to set dynamic values with onKeyUp javascript?

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

How can I set dynamic values for function onKeyUp? Right now I'm hardcoding the number but I need to retrieve it from a php variable.

**php value**

```
$num = $queryResults['col_number'];
```

**html**

```
<input onKeyUp="if(this.value>'$num'){this.value='$num';}
else if(this.value<0){this.value='0';}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output the value using `<?php echo $num ?>` or shorter `<?= $num ?>`

```
<input onKeyUp="if(this.value>'<?= $num ?>'){this.value='<?= $num ?>';} else if(this.value<0){this.value='0';}" />
```